# Facebook SDK PHP publicar en Página

Tags: php, facebook

Tengo una cuenta creada en Facebook Developers, yun token generado que nunca expira.
Desde PHP publico correctamente mi post de mi página en Facebook. El problema que sólo yo puedo ver esa publicación. Ni se publica en mi perfil ni en mi página. Queda en un sitio intermedio donde sólo yo puedo verlo.

La app en Facebook Developers esta activa y publicada. Quiero que mis posts de mi blog se publiquen directamente en mi página.

Mi código es simple y funciona perfecto.

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session_facebook, 'POST', '/'.$ID.'/feed', $params
            ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Los permisos de mi token son, entre otros, manage_pages y publish_actions. Tengo lo mismo en otro proyecto y se publica correctamente. Alguna sugerencia? Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no esta redactado en español

Comment: Por favor, traduce la respuesta al español o será eliminada. Si realmente quieres preguntar en inglés, hazlo en http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Ya está traducido. Lo siento, no sabia que había una versión en español. Gracias por la aclaración. Tenéis alguna sugerencia del problema? Gracias

Comment: @SergioGarrido solo por curiosidad, si no sabias que había una versión en español, ¿como llegaste a esta página?

Comment: Puse stackovarflow en Google y redacté. Ya me extrañó ver todo en castellano, jajaja

Comment: ¿Qué permisos tienes puestos en Facebook para tu aplicación? Podría ocurrir que (como usuario) sólo estés compartiendo los posts de tu aplicación contigo por defecto (yo lo hacía para no molestar a mis amigos con posts de prueba)

Comment: Tengo manage_pages y publish_actions

Comment: @SergioGarrido Esos permisos los tienes en la aplicación como desarrollador. Pero si vas a tu perfil normal de Facebook, le das a configuración -> aplicaciones, puedes ver los permisos que tiene esa aplicación a la hora de publicar (mira que no sea "sólo yo"). Seguramente no sea eso, pero por asegurarte no pierdes nada

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ir a dev de Facebook y poner que la aplicación es publica, porque estas en versión de prueba, tienes que publicarla, poner los logos de la app etc.. Y explicar como funciona la app y lo seguro te van a pedir un streaming de como funciona, para que le den el visto bueno los chicos de facebook.

Comment: aunque sólo la quiera para uso interno mio tengo que hacer todo eso???

Answer (score 1):

Los tokens ahora tienen una caducidad de 3 meses, así que cuidado. De todas formas tienes que generar el token seleccionando en el desplegable la página en la que quieres publicar y en vez de usar '/'.$ID.'/feed', directamente '/me/feed'
He creado un manual de como hacerlo, porque es algo tedioso el proceso: 
http://www.primemonkey.com/publicar-facebook-desde-php/
Y recuerda marcar la aplicación como pública.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que cuando iniciaste sesion la primera vez en la app pusiste en la privacidad "Solo Yo" y tal vez por eso solo tu vez la publicacion, intenta ir a facebook y en  configuracion/aplicaciones y elimina tu aplicacion luego vuelve iniciar sesion pero esta vez escoje que todos puedan ver las publicaciones.